# How to store data in SQLite database fetched using web service from backend server?

Tags: android, sqlite, web-services

I am beginner and working on an Andorid App in which I am getting data from server through back-end web service and now I want to store that data in SQLite database? How to do it?

Comment: what you tried so far ?

Comment: @GaneshPatil  i just get the data from server and receiving through my back-end service....Now i wanna to get the data that service class and store in sqlite. How to do this?

Comment: `SQLiteOpenHelper` - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing data in SQLite Database android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33174579/storing-data-in-sqlite-database-android)

Comment: Post your efforts first ehat you did to store data in sqlite database.

Answer (score 1):

First open or create database like below code.

```
SQLiteDatabase db1; = openOrCreateDatabase("shiftDB.db", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
```

Then create table like below. My table name is shift_master.

```
db1.execSQL("create table IF NOT EXISTS shift_master(shift_id numeric, shift_name text, start_time time, end_time time)");
```

If you are getting data in a json array then insert data in sqlite table like below.

```
JSONArray shift= obj.getJSONArray("shiftLst");

for (int j = 0; j < shift.length(); j++) {
     JSONObject innerElem = shift.getJSONObject(j);
     db1.execSQL("Insert into shift_master(shift_id, shift_name, start_time, end_time) Values (" + innerElem.getInt("shift_id") + ",'" + innerElem.getString("shift_name") + "','" + innerElem.getString("start_time") + "','" + innerElem.getString("end_time") + "')");
}
```

Comment: brother i just get an idea but dont understand where to write db code? or do the above code in my service class when i get respond from server

Comment: Create or open database in oncreate method then create table in on create method. now insert data where you get response from your service.

Comment: for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                    db.execSQL("Insert into Employee(COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_JOBTYPE, COLUMN_TIME) Values (" + jsonObject.get("userid") + ",'" + jsonObject.getString("job_type") + "','" + jsonObject.getString("start_time") + "')");
                                   
                                }

Comment: i wrote that code where i will get response but its not working i think i should use database handler(Class) object instead of db.execSQL.  
i am using SQLiteDatabase db as an object for insertion